# Scala collections flowchart

Tags: scala, collections

There is a nice flowchart (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699265/)) for choosing a particular container in C++:

[image: container-flowchart]

Is there something similar for the Scala collections? I'm still somewhat overwhelmed with the options.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I am not aware of such flowcharts for Scala, but I guess one would be useful.
I made one for you -- larger picture [**here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXyxZ.png).

Note that there is some added complexity, since Scala has more collections and there is both the `mutable` and the `immutable` package. Where possible, I added both alternatives to the rectangle.

I tried to follow the C++ STL flow diagram as much as possible, but I thought that the lower left part was complicating things a bit too much, so I changed the flow there slightly.

EDIT: fixed some typos.

EDIT: As Travis, suggested, note that in a majority of situations, you only need to pick between a `Map`, `Set`, `List`, `ArrayBuffer` or a `Vector`.

- if you need key-value lookup, use a `Map`
- if you need to check for presence of elements, use a `Set`
- if you need to store elements and traverse them, use a `List` or an `ArrayBuffer`
- if you don't need a persistent collection, but random access is really important, use `ArrayBuffer`
- if you need relatively fast random access and persistent sequences, use `Vector`

If that does not help and you have a more exotic use-case, use this chart.

[image]

Comment: That's a rather nice flowchart. What did you use to make it?

Comment: The CorelDRAW application. It's pretty nice to use for vector graphics.

Comment: The vast majority of the time in idiomatic Scala you'll be using `Map`, `Set`, `List`, and `Vector` (or `Seq` and `IndexedSeq` for the last two, according to some people). This is a handy chart, but it may make the situation seem even more confusing than it really is.

Comment: That's a good point. I think I'll edit my answer to point that out.

Comment: Nice chart, but immutable.HashMap is located on both sides of question "Order is important". That is a bit confusing.

Comment: If insertion order is not important, one can use `immutable.HashMap`. If insertion order is important, `immutable.HashMap` can be used together with `immutable.TreeMap` to track insertion order - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9313866/immutable-scala-map-implementation-that-preserves-insertion-order. One could also use `ListMap` for that, but with `O(n)` lookup.

Comment: @axel22 care to update this excellent flowchart for Scala 2.13?