# the order of keys in scala map

Tags: scala, dictionary

i need to get the keys from map in the order when they are added. but seems the map.keys return a array with re-ordered keys.

how to keep the order of the key/values as they added when retrieve them ?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9313866/immutable-scala-map-implementation-that-preserves-insertion-order)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scala Map implementation keeping entries in insertion order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835743/scala-map-implementation-keeping-entries-in-insertion-order)

Answer (score 3):

Maps implemented using trees don't store their keys in the order that they are inserted. That information is lost when it's inserted by value (based on its `Comparable`), and further "randomized" when the tree is balanced.

As @mziccard pointed out, linear structures (such as a `LinkedHashMap`) can preserve insertion order, so that's the way to go if you need such a capability.

Comment: In Scala you have both a mutable map (LinkedHashMap) and an immutable one (LinkedMap) that allow you to preserve insertion order. Also Java has its LinkedHashMap preserving insertion order and capable also to track access order if required.

Comment: My bad. I was thinking specifically of BST implementations. I'll correct that and reference you.